# Run Apache Servicemx on Raspi

Tags: java

Does anyone have experiences in running an Apache Servicemix on a Raspi? I wonder if the memory is enough for that. I would like to use the Raspi as Server for my Note Service when Im not using it with XBMC.

Comment: Did you get this to work? Which model did you use (256/512 MB)?

Comment: no, i canceled this project due to lack of time